# Regarding $x^2-a^2$ inside the argument of dirac delta

Tags: integration, signal-processing

My undergraduate system textbook has this property in the appendix 
$$\delta(x^2-a^2)=\frac{1}{2|a|}[\delta(x-a)+\delta(x+a)]$$
and I can't seem to derive the result

I tried the following:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x^2-a^2)\, dx$

let $u^2=x^2-a^2$ and $x=\sqrt{u^2-a^2}$ however I couldn't resolve the new limit of integral as $u$ must be strictly positive under this substitution. What is another way I can approach this?

Comment: Informally: $\delta(x^2−a^2)=\delta((x+a)(x-a))$ which only "weights" at $x=-a$ and $x=a$. Around $x \to a$, this behaves as $\delta(2a (x-a) )$ which by the [scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry) property is $ \frac{1}{|2 a|}\delta(x-a)$. Summing up the other term, at $x= -a$, we get your formula.

Answer (score 15):

Let $x=\sqrt{u}$, so $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}$, then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\delta(x^2-a^2)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}}\delta(u-a^2)\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{f(|a|)}{2|a|}.$$
Let $x=-\sqrt{u}$, so $\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}$, then
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\delta(x^2-a^2)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{f(-\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}}\delta(u-a^2)\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{f(-|a|)}{2|a|}.$$
Hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\delta(x^2-a^2)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2|a|}\left(f(|a|)+f(-|a|)\right) = \frac{1}{2|a|}\left(f(a)+f(-a)\right).$$

Comment: How do you change the integration boundaries from $-\infty, 0$  to  $ 0,+\infty $ on the second line

Comment: By changing the limits he inverts the sign of the function.